# How to dynamically query for a column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, metadata

Consider the following piece of SQL code for a PostgreSQL DBMS (9.3):

```
SELECT 
    column_name, (SELECT count(*) FROM _TABLE_NAME_ WHERE column_name = 'X')
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_schema = '_SCHEMA_NAME_'
AND 
    table_name = '_TABLE_NAME_';
```

I want to use the retrieved column_names from the outer query in the inner query as column names (meta). Is there a way to do this in one SELECT statement (multiple inner SELECT statements are ok too)?

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not my work. I asked a colleague and after Jakub Kania's idea with `json_each_text` and `row_to_json` he came to the following solution which exactly answers my question.

```
SELECT 
    k, sum((v = 'X')::INT)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        (json_each_text(row_to_json(_TABLE_NAME_WITHOUT_SCHEMA_))).KEY AS k, 
        (json_each_text(row_to_json(_TABLE_NAME_WITHOUT_SCHEMA_))).VALUE AS v
    FROM 
        _TABLE_NAME_
) AS tmp
GROUP BY k;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need meta tables, you need an unpivot query. With a reasonably recent pg you can achieve it with [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) like this:

```
SELECT key
      ,count(*) FILTER (WHERE value = 'X') 
FROM  _TABLE_NAME_
      ,json_each_text(row_to_json( _TABLE_NAME_)) AS unpivot
GROUP BY key;
```